# Как возвращать значения из хранимой процедуры MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, syntax, stored-procedures

Начал изучать MySQL после 20 лет работы с SQL Server. 95% моих запросов к базе - вызовы хранимых процедур, о которых в SQL Server я знаю чуть более чем всё. 20 лет практики и успешной реализации многих проектов на SQL Server убедили меня в том, что в использовании хранимых процедур всё-таки больше достоинств чем недостатков.

Однако многие конструкции в MySQL кажутся мне не очень удобными и не практичными. Разумеется, это моё субъективное восприятие. Кроме того, я изучаю синтаксис MySQL всего лишь пару недель, поэтому прошу не критиковать меня за реплику выше. Сравнение получилось вынужденным и необъективным.

Мой вопрос заключается в том, что я не могу найти в MySQL аналога очень удобного кода на Transact-SQL:

```
create procedure my_stored_proc
  @p1 varchar(15),
  @p2 char10
as

set nocount on

declare @id int

select @id = some_id from some_table
where (some_val1 = @p1) or (some_val2 = @p2)
--я точно знаю, что после запроса выше @id будет инициализирован

select @id as 'Identifier'
--значение @id просто возьмёт и вернётся в вызывающий код
```

Пожалуйста, обратите внимание на то, что я в теле процедуры объявляю переменную, затем инициализирую её и хочу вернуть её значение под алиасом.

Как мне реализовать подобное на MySQL?
Я испробовал всё что нашел на просторах Сети - играл с параметрами (in/out/inout), явно подставлял значения, и проч. Но хранимая процедура всегда возвращает NULL.

**UPDATE**

Как это обычно бывает, я разобрался самостоятельно только лишь после того, как чётко формализовал проблему в виде вопроса. Вот моё решение:

```
set @id = 0;

select @id = some_id from some_table
where (some_val1 = @p1) or (some_val2 = @p2)

select @id as 'Identifier';
```

То есть `declare` вообще не для объявления локальной переменной, да? Я просто беру переменную (без явного объявления) и инициализирую её нулём, робко надеясь, что MySQL поймёт что переменная будет типа `int`. Вопрос: а если мне нужен будет `bigint`? Как MySQL решает какого типа должна быть инициализируемая переменная?

Ну и с возвратом значения тоже все понятно. Синтаксис ничем не отличается от Transact-SQL.

Я буду признателен за более изящные решения (если они есть).

Comment: MySQL-процедура будет выглядеть почти так же. А вот вернуть куда-то результат нельзя в принципе - в MySQL не существует табличного типа данных. Так что результат выполнения процедуры можно получить только в клиента как набор записей, точно так же, как и результат обычного запроса.

Comment: @Akina, _>Так что результат выполнения процедуры можно получить только в клиента как набор записей_ -- спасибо, а можно ли пример? Вызываю процедуру я при помощи Workbench. Разве мне не должно вернутся значение типа int?

Comment: В воркбенче Вы получите набор записей. Такой же, какой Вы получаете, выполняя обычный SELECT. Просто этот набор будет состоять из одной записи, которая состоит из одного поля. А если надо получить "значение типа INT" - то его можно получить в пользовательскую переменную (откуда потом извлечь отдельным SELECT, либо использовать в другом запросе).

Comment: *В воркбенче Вы получите набор записей.* Если более точно - в воркбенче при запуске процедуры Вы получаете массив наборов записей. Просто в данном конкретном случае этот массив состоит из одного элемента.

Comment: Не знаю насчет корректности, но мое решение работает и выполняет задачи, передо мной стоящие; не знаю что такое анонимный код; про `declare` обязательно почитаю, спасибо; а почему мой вопрос неформат? Уверен, что вопрос соответствует правилам ru.SO. Я искал решение и в итоге его нашёл. Не оформляю свою находку ответом ибо жду более изящного решения/-ий.

Comment: Код должен работать в теле sp, я же это подчеркнул. В программировании _opinion-based_ == _approach-based_. Когда творцы предлагают свои подходы, идеи и техники в решении задач. Именно это я тут и искал. Так что я не вижу темы для дальнейшей переписки и не смогу больше продолжать этот разговор.

Comment: Ну нет так нет. Хотя на мой взгляд, ixbt.com или sql.ru куда как больше подходят для этой темы.